# Expo facebook login fails: error : server with the specified hostname could not be found?

Tags: react-native, expo, facebook-login

UPDATE: it works in the IOS simulator, but only doesnt work in my expo go app.

I have an expo react native managed app. I tried to implement the facebook login but I always get the following error:

[image]

my code (there should not be problems with it, its just the sample code from expo)

```
const AuthScreen = () => {
import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook';
    const loginWithFacebook = async () => {
        try {
            await Facebook.initializeAsync({
                appId: '<MYAPPID>',
            });
            const {type, token, expirationDate, permissions, declinedPermissions} =
                await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync({
                    permissions: ['public_profile'],
                });
            if (type === 'success') {
                const response = await fetch(`https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`);
                Alert.alert('Logged in!', `Hi ${(await response.json()).name}!`);
            } else {
                // type === 'cancel'
            }
        } catch ({message}) {
            alert(`Facebook Login Error: ${message}`);
        }
    };

    return (

            <FontAwesome.Button name="facebook" onPress={loginWithFacebook}>Login With Facebook</FontAwesome.Button>
           
    )
};
```

What I did so when registering my app:

1. in facebook developers I created my app 'rainy'.
2. In settings/basic I added IOS and Android.

   a. in IOS I only added host.exp.Exponent as the Bundle ID

   b. In android I only added the hash key: rRW++LUjmZZ+58EbN5DVhGAnkX4= (I couldnt find that hash on expo docs anymore but found it elsewhere and it should be up to date)
3. in app.json I added infoPlist with properties to ios as following:

```
...
  "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "facebookScheme": "fb<MYAPPID>",
        "facebookAppId": "<MYAPPID>",
        "FacebookClientToken": "abcxxxxx", //got it from Settings > Advanced > Client Token
        "facebookDisplayName": "rainy",
        "facebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled": false,
        "facebookAdvertiserIDCollectionEnabled": false
      }
    },
...
```

4. I wasnt sure but also (after getting the error) tried to add to Valid OAuth Redirect URIs the following: https://auth.expo.io/@/rainy. not sure if even needed but the error is still the same

Also I expo installed expo-facebook.

Did I miss any step or did something wrong? Thank you!!